# Can 受付 be used like a verb meaning "to check in" at a hotel etc?

Tags: translation, verbs

On a YouTube video I just watched, an interviewer is challenging Japanese people to speak pure Japanese with no English loanwords (Chinese loanwords must be considered pure for some reason though) and one of the challenges is "what do you do when you arrive at a hotel?"

In the video comments it's been suggested that 受付 means "check in" but I can't find that sense. I can find it being used as a noun so perhaps "reception desk" or something.

A more generic English word would be "register". Native speakers tend not to use that for hotels since "check in" is more specific. Would there be a Japanese word for "to register" that would also work for "to check in"? Would 受付 be closest? What about 審査?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

受付 is a noun that means "reception desk".

受付け(を)する or 受付けを済ませる mean "check in".

受付けに行く means "to go to the reception desk". He may check in or just may ask receptionists for information about something.